# Insert block of text in file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting

I am editing an Arch base installation script. I almost got it to work as I wanted!

I need to add the following into the end of /etc/pacman.conf

```
[archlinuxfr]
SigLevel = Never
Server = http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch
```

Before I used cat command and it deleted everything inside /etc/pacman.conf and just added this. But I need to add it to the end of the file.

Here is the script I currently have: https://github.com/ArchT420/T420/blob/master/installer.sh

Thank you!

Comment: You can use below command

Comment: sed -r  '$s/.*/&\n\[archlinuxfr\]\nSigLevel = Never\nServer = http:\/\/repo.archlinux.fr\/\$arch/g'  filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't we simply use `echo` to append the context to a file.

```
echo -e '[archlinuxfr]\nSigLevel = Never\nServer = http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch' >> /home/user/Documents/pacman.conf
```

Answer (score 7):

This solution seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash


## Add AUR repository in /etc/pacman.conf
cat <<EOF >> /mnt/etc/pacman.conf
[archlinuxfr]
SigLevel = Never
Server = http://repo.archlinux.fr/\$arch
EOF
```